# convert QString to Gbytes

Tags: c, qt, gtk, glib, qstring

want to convert a QString to GBytes (glib)

I tried the following by converting the QString to GByteArray and than 
freeing it to GBytes

```
extern "C" {
#include <glib.h>
};
#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

QString mylongstring = "HELLO_WORLD";

GByteArray *barr;
barr = g_byte_array_new ();

for (int i = 0; i < mylongstring.toLocal8Bit().count(); i++)
{
     guint8 *charAt = (guint8*)mylongstring.at(i); //cant convert qchar to uint -> already crashes

    g_byte_array_append (barr, (guint8*) charAt, 1); 
}
GBytes *gbytes = g_byte_array_free_to_bytes(barr); //should contain the (guint8*) data of mylongstring

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: And can we assume that it did not work as intended? In which way? What happens? What should happen? Also, please provide more code context, make a [mcve].

Comment: Update description.

Comment: It looks like you updated the code but there still is no description.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take the `GByteArray` from the `QByteArray` ? whats the purpose of the loop ?

I think your cast is causing the issue because it does not allocate enough bytes, check this : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data

rewriting your code, by taking `GByteArray` from QByteArray `data()` seems safer ..

```
QByteArray _string2BA = mylongstring.toLocal8Bit();
char *data = new char[_string2BA.size() + 1];
strcpy(data, _string2BA.data());
GByteArray *barr;
barr = g_byte_array_new ();
barr = (GByteArray*)data;

GBytes *gbytes = g_byte_array_free_to_bytes(barr); //should contain the (guint8*) data of mylongstring
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines you have to change:

```
guint8 *charAt = (guint8*)mylongstring.at(i);
g_byte_array_append (barr, (guint8*) charAt, 1);
```

to

```
guint8 charAt = (guint8)mylongstring.toLocal8Bit().at(i);
g_byte_array_append (barr, &charAt, 1);
```

But consider this.

> Returns the local 8-bit representation of the string as a QByteArray.
>   The returned byte array is undefined if the string contains characters
>   not supported by the local 8-bit encoding.
>   [source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit)